# Process rows of R dataframe without loop in memory efficient way

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

The structure of my dataframe `data1`, which has over 1.5 million rows, is like this:

```
data1 <- data.frame(NEW_UPC=c(11820005991,11820005991,11820005991,11820005991,11820005991,11820005991,11820005991,11820005991,11820005991,11820005991,11820005991,11820005991,11820005992,11820005992,11820005992,11820005992,11820005992,11820005992,11820005992,11820005992,11820005992,11820005993,11820005993,11820005993,11820005993,11820005993,11820005993,11820005993,11820005993,11820005993,11820005994,11820005994,11820005994,11820005994,11820005994,11820005994,11820005995,11820005995,11820005995,11820005995,11820005995,11820005995,11820005995,11820005995,11820005995),
                IRI_KEY=c(1073521,1073521,1073521,1073525,1073525,1073525,1078106,1078106,1078106,1078107,1078107,1078107,1073521,1073521,1073521,1073525,1073525,1073525,1078106,1078106,1078106,1073521,1073521,1073521,1073525,1073525,1073525,1078106,1078106,1078106,1073521,1073521,1073525,1073525,1078106,1078106,1073521,1073521,1073521,1073525,1073525,1073525,1078106,1078106,1078106),
                WEEK = c(1229,1230,1232,1218,1224,1229,1282,1285,1287,1229,1230,1232,1229,1230,1232,1218,1224,1229,1282,1285,1287,1229,1230,1232,1217,1221,1227,1270,1272,1273,1273,1274,1270,1272,1217,1221,1229,1230,1232,1218,1224,1229,1282,1285,1287),
                END=c(1232,1232,1232,1229,1229,1229,1287,1287,1287,1232,1232,1232,1232,1232,1232,1229,1229,1229,1287,1287,1287,1232,1232,1232,1227,1227,1227,1273,1273,1273,1274,1274,1272,1272,1221,1221,1232,1232,1232,1229,1229,1229,1287,1287,1287))
```

I need to insert a column `Exit.time` using values in columns `WEEK` and `END` and a cutoff value, which is 1287. `Exit.time` should have 0 or 1 value based on the following logic:

if `WEEK` = 1287, then `Exit.time` = 0.

if `Week` not equal to 1287, but `WEEK` = `END` then `Exit.time` = 1, otherwise `Exit.time` = 0.

For this I tried the following for loop and it does what is required in the above dummy data set.

```
i=0
for(i in 1:length(data2$NEW_UPC)){
  if (data2$WEEK[i]==1287) {
    data2$Exit.time[i] <- 0
  } else if(data2$WEEK[i]==data2$END[i]) {
    data2$Exit.time[i] <- 1
  } else {
    data2$Exit.time[i] <- 0
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I use the above loop in my real data set, even after an hour I am not getting an output. I guess looping is not efficient given the size of the dataset. Is there an alternative way to do what I want? I prefer to maintain the order of rows in `data1` since I need to do some merge operations later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need `Exit.time` to be 1 when `(WEEK == END) & WEEK != 1287` and 0 otherwise, you can use `as.numeric` on the results of `(WEEK == END) & WEEK != 1287`, which changes `TRUE` to `1` and `FALSE` to `0`.

```
data1$Exit.time <- with(data1, as.numeric(WEEK != 1287 & WEEK == END))
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to code this, mostly differing in the semantics, they are fundamentally doing the same thing

Base R:

```
data1$Exit.time <- (data1$WEEK != 1287 & data1$WEEK == data1$END)*1
```

This involves typing `data1` a lot, so there is a short-cut:

```
data1 <- within(data1, {
  Exit.time <- (WEEK != 1287 & WEEK == END)*1
})
```

Tidyverse:
Tidyverse is a suite of packages which are great at manipulating data.  We are using the package `dplyr`, which is part of `tidyverse`, so you can either load the whole thing, or just `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
data1 <- data1 %>%
   mutate(
     Exit.time = (WEEK != 1287 & WEEK == END)*1
   )
```

(I convert from TRUE/FALSE to 0/1 by multiplying by 1.  It's less to type)

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
setDT(data1)[, Exit.time := ifelse(WEEK == 1287, 0, ifelse(WEEK != 1287 & WEEK == END, 1, 0))]
```